# Mongodb $sample after filtering

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I want a person to find people they're not connected with, I would do:

```
User.find({ _id: { $nin: req.user.connections })
```

However, I only want to retrieve at most 10 random documents from the return. In MongoDB, there is $sample:

```
{ $sample: { size: <positive integer> } }
```

I've never used Mongo before, so I'm unsure of how to chain these two together in order  for me to retrieve 10 random people the current user is unconnected to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) is an aggregation operator, so you need to create an `aggregate` pipeline that chains the two operations together:

```
User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: { $nin: req.user.connections } } },
    { $sample: { size: 10 } }
])
```